# ChatGPTでFineTuneしたモデルを削除する方法

Tags: python3, chatgpt, 人工知能

OpenAIのAPI(Python版)を利用して、ファインチューニング(追加学習)をしています。
ファインチューニングを実施しモデルを作成することはできたのですが、削除することができません。
削除するメソッド(API)が見当たらないのですが、
どのように削除すればよいか教えていただけないでしょうか？

https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/main/api.mdの、
client.fine_tunes.create(**params)メソッドにより、ファインチューニングはできました。
ためしに、client.models.delete(model)で、
ファインチューニングしたモデルのIDをして削除を試しましたが、
そのようなモデルはないとのエラーが発生し、削除することができませんでした。

```
NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'message': "The model 'ft-Ou8aW1syt9jmutpuYVTiTol4' does not exist", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'model', 'code': 'model_not_found'}}
```

また、
FineTuningパッケージと
FineTunesパッケージの違いは何でしょうか？
（FineTunesは古いVersionの非推奨パッケージで、
FineTuningパッケージが新しく推奨されているものでしょうか？）